# What linux distro allows full encryption when dual booting from windows 11

Tags: linux

I want to install a distro to work with windows when I dual boot.

I know that lubuntu allows full disk encryption, but it doesnt encrypt /boot. I am also aware to this ubuntu guide:

```
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Full_Disk_Encryption_Howto_2019
```

I dont know what solution to choose. I dont want anyone to eject my nvme ssd (I have kingston brand) and be able to read my data.

Note that I have a password on the boot screen before any OS loads. I dont have my windows 11 fully encrypted, and I am looking for a security solution that will allow me to work in a safe environment. I could upgrade my windows from home to enterprise edition in order to get the bitlocker feature, but I would rather not pay, and I dont trust windows.

Comment: If you’re willing to put `/boot` on a usb key you can probably use just about any distribution with full encryption on the nvme device.

Comment: Turn bitlocker on in Windows and install Ubuntu in LVM with encryption to the remaining space. Grub now boots without /boot, but you will need unencrypted ESP for UEFI to boot it.

Comment: @doneal24, do you know a good guide on how I can achieve so with Ubuntu and a usb stick?

Comment: I have not tried it but the instructions [here](https://tqdev.com/2022-luks-with-usb-unlock) look reasonable.

Comment: @oldfred The OP already said he did not want to upgrade to Windows Enterprise (or Pro) so bitlocker is not an option.

Comment: I do not know of any Linux encryption that works for Windows. I have seen this, but know nothing about it.   There is Veracrypt which replaced truecrypt not strictly open source. https://www.veracrypt.fr/code/VeraCrypt/

Comment: @oldfred Other option is to run Linux on a fully-encrypted disk and then have Windows installed as a virtual machine. btw g1D9wo9NhobXaCjp7MCe, if you go with the boot from USB key, make sure you have at least one physical backup of the key kept in a secure location. Losing the key means no access to the laptop.